# How to Parse DataContract object to xml?

Tags: wcf

I define some class as 'DataContract'

I need to save this object in my database ( as xml ) before i sending it to the client.

When the .net framework send this object to the client - the object parse to xml - so i want to hold this xml and add it to my Database

How can i do it ? 
How can i get this xml without / before the sending to the client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DataContractSerializer in System.Runtime.Serialization to get an XDocument

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateWriter())
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                serializer.WriteObject(writer, obj);
                writer.Close();
            }
            return doc;
```

where obj is your object and T is the type of your object

Comment: Why you need the      ' MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); '   ?

Comment: the the write.close() - its something that will be call by the end of the 'using' scop

Comment: You don't.  I copied that from one of our classes.  Good catch.  Thanks for the input.